# Choosing a method to solve a many-to-one mapping problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multiple-regression, neural-networks, multivariate-analysis

## Problem description

To predict a list of values associated with a set of variables.

### Trainset

Trainset has a set of variables X1, X2, X3, ... Xn. In the simplest form, each variable is of type numeric with different ranges. The largest range being 1-100000 and the smallest range being 1-10. 
Target is a list of numbers(Y) whose range is again 1-100000. The list is of variable length so each observation has varying number of targets. Could assume that the target list is a list of item IDs.

**Example of the train subset** (X1, X2, X3... Xn => {Y})

Observation1: 2345, 23, 8, ... 99399 => {2345, 98755}

Observation2: 45276, 3, 1, ... 80001 => {7865, 98675, 78954}

and so on...

**Prediction**

So, prediction is a list of numbers that can vary depending on the variable values.

**My thoughts**

---

1. Looks like a multi label classification problem with each label corresponding to a single value in the prediction list.
2. But because the range of the labels is large (i.e. 1-100000), cannot use a classification method.
3. Probably can use multi target regression method to predict a list of targets for an observation in the test set.
4. Assuming Ym is the maximum length of the prediction list in the training set. Could fill the prediction list in Observation1 of the training set as:

   Observation1: 2345, 23, 8, ... 99399 => {2345, 98755, 0 , ... 0} (0 representing empty value which is repeated Ym-2 times)
5. Might be worth normalizing all the variables and values in the prediction list.

**Questions**

1. Am I missing something ? Is this method appropriate for this kind of problem ?
2. The values in the prediction list are identifiers so they do not have a direct correlation with other values & variables in the observation. And this is a concern that worries me. Will it be a major concern if I use a multi target regression ?
3. What kind of methods can I use ? neural network or linear regression ?
4. Because the complete set of targets is known during training, could a clustering method be used as I am trying to predict a cluster of items that correspond to an observation ?

Comment: I am no expert in artificial neural networks (ANNs) but have a gut feeling that an ANN would be the way to go here (a regression 'mapping' from multiple input variables to multiple output variables). I think your points in 4 and 5 are quite sensible. Might be helpful to add the ANN tag to the question to draw the attention of the right audience.

Comment: The variable dimension thing is... Messy. Are you absolutely sure you've formulated the problem correctly?

Comment: @ssdecontrol: If you are referring to multiple targets for each observation when you say 'variable dimension' then I am pretty certain that I formulated the problem correctly.

Comment: @iceBreak it's not just having multiple targets, it's also that the number of targets varies

Comment: @ssdecontrol I formulated this problem from this scenario: The variables used in the problem are parameters defining a particular device used by a person and the targets I am trying to predict are all the cookies associated with it. So variables are things like what type of device it is, country the device belongs to, etc. and each target is an id representing a cookie on that device. So, number of cookies associated a device will vary and I need to predict more than one target for a device.

Comment: @iceBreak and how many unique cookies do you have?

Comment: @iceBreak you will never be able to predict the existence of a cookie that isn't in your training set and that's a problem for classification. You could try 1-class classification with a known set of cookies as the one class then work on the known set using multiclass classification. If you did this in an online fashion then you could add (retrain) newly discovered cookies into the known set. I'd imagine, that offline or online, it'd be better done in one algorithm but I'm not sure what that cost function would look like.

Comment: @ssdecontrol certaining lot many... The problem description I gave is representative of the real problem so there are around 100000 unique cookies.

Comment: I wonder if regression might be the wrong way to look at this problem. Maybe there's some kind of algorithm/learner/model that describes the kind of "many to one matching" you're talking about. Possibly something related to [ontology matching](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/hois.pdf). And @MeadowlarkBradsher makes a good point that you'll only ever be able to predict cookies that you've already observed.

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher Infact, I would expect that the predicted cookies are always from the training set.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Infact, I would expect that the predicted cookies are always from the training set.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to assume that, conditional on a device's features, each cookie appears independently. In that case, you can fit a SVM or decision tree or some other classifier (I don't recommend logistic regression for classification), with the appearance of each cookie being a binary outcome. This means you have one model for each cookie. Yes, this means you are training 100,000 separate classifiers, each on who-knows-how-many data points. But the theoretical framework is straightforward and the computational challenge is not insurmountable

Comment: Actually, this is an interesting approach but I am concerned about the computational challenge when #cookies increases. My example has only 100,000 cookies but in reality the #cookies are humongous which might make it computationally impractical.

Comment: @iceBreak you're right, which is why I was hesitant to post this. But it will depend on how big "humongous" really is, and on how fast your classifier can be trained